# ¿Cómo leer un float de un archivo de texto con C?

Tags: c

Dado un **archivo de texto** con el siguiente formato:

3.45

56.90

-12.909

Es decir, **el formato presenta un float por línea. ¿Cómo puedo leer los float para manipularlos** como variables, guardarlos en un array o lo que quiera hacer con ellos?

**El nombre del fichero** a leer es introducido como **único parámetro** a través de la línea de **comandos** (argv(1) contiene ejemplo.txt, por ejemplo).

Comment: `fscanf("%f", &variable_tipo_float, f)` siendo `f` el resultado de abrir el fichero para lectura con `fopen()`

Comment: @abulafia Creo que el fichero es el primer argumento, y no el ultimo. [Documentacion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: @Pablochaches Toda la razón, siempre me confundo,por culpa de `fgets()`, que sí lleva el fichero al final.

Comment: ¿Por qué escribimos la dirección donde se almacena la variable tipo float y no su contenido? Es decir, ¿por qué &variable_tipo_float y no variable_tipo_float? Imagino que tiene que ver con la implementación de la función fscanf, pero tampoco sé dónde puedo mirar la misma

Comment: abufalia, escriba su respuesta para puntuarla. Gracias